# Ability to use generics in keyvaluepair when using params as a parameter on a method

Tags: c#

Is something like this possible?

```
public bool SetAttribute(
    string entity, params KeyValuePair<T, T>[] attributes)
```

Where I could then have a foreach of attributes and check the typeof value of the keyvaluepair or even

```
public bool SetAttribute(
    string entity, params KeyValuePair<string, T>[] attributes)
```

or do I just do

```
 public bool SetAttribute(
      string entity, params KeyValuePair<oject, object>[] attributes)
```

or

```
public bool SetAttribute(
     string entity, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] attributes)
```

Comment: You might be able to use a dynamic, but I am not sure. Dynamic is basically the same as a var in JavaScript

Comment: If the types aren't known at compile-time, you cannot use generic types, use `KeyValuePair<string, object>` (or `object, object` if you so require). It depends on what you want to do

Comment: You can state that the method is generic like `public bool SetAttribute<T>(...)` and in the params definition receive a parameter like `KeyValuePair<string, T> kv`. Note that `T` will need to have the same restrictions or more that those in  `KeyValuePair`